# Generating all possible combinations of the elements of a vector in R

Tags: r

Having the vector,

```
v1 <- LETTERS[1:4]
```

I would like to get a two-columns data.frame of the type:

```
A B 

A C

A D

B A

B C

B D

D A

D B

D C
```

I have tried with `combn`, outer and `expand.grid` but I didn’t get what I wanted.

Comment: your expected output is not clear. You generate A D and D A but no values with C. You can try either `expand.grid(v1, v1)` or `combn(v1, 2)`

Comment: You are right! Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(seq_along(v1), function(i) data.frame(x = v1[i], y = v1[-i])))
```

OR

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(seq_along(v1), function(i){
    do.call(rbind, lapply(seq_along(v1)[-i], function(j){
        c(v1[i], v1[j])
    }))
}))
```

OR

```
d = expand.grid(replicate(2, v1, simplify = FALSE))
d[d$Var1 != d$Var2,]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
outer(v1, v1, paste, sep="")
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,] "AA" "AB" "AC" "AD"
[2,] "BA" "BB" "BC" "BD"
[3,] "CA" "CB" "CC" "CD"
[4,] "DA" "DB" "DC" "DD"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want all possible combinations of AA - DD in two columns, you can use the tidyr `crossing` function.

This would be my approach:

```
library(tidyverse)

v1 <- LETTERS[1:4]
v2 <- v1

final_df <- crossing(v1, v2)
```

Answer (score 0):

All solutions are perfectly fine. And with one extra line of command you can filter out the row that contain A A, and B B, and C C, and D D.

Using the example by Matt,

final_df <- final_df %>% 
    filter(v1 != v2)

Thanks!